# strapi - fetch data to enumeration field and select multiple values

Tags: strapi

I need to add a multiple select field (as a component or many to many relation) to the collection type.
But I want to fetch data from an external API and show it in the dropdown.
can I know how to achieve such kind of implementation?

because strapi won't allow fetching data to a collection type field from external API

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38305154/why-enum-does-not-store-multiple-values-in-mysql

Comment: @MarsAndBack this has nothing to do with the question 

Answer (score 1):

Strapi as at the time of answering this question does not allow multiple selections for an enumeration field.

The possible way I would recommend is creating the Content-type field as a JSON. Then in your backend controller, you do the checking before validating the data.

Answer (score 0):

For Strapi version 4.4.0 and above there is a custom filed plugin that gives you the ability to have a multiple select field. Here is the link --> https://market.strapi.io/plugins/strapi-plugin-multi-select

As for the functionality of fetching data from an external API, here are some ideas that may work.

- create a plugin to work with the *multi select input* plugin, or0
- extend the plugin's functionality --> https://docs.strapi.io/dev-docs/plugins-extension, or
- implement the custom functionality directly in Strapi's src directory

Hope this helps...